# Question on the final step of Hanson's proof that $\prod\limits_{p^a \le n}p^a < 3^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, proof-explanation, multinomial-coefficients

In Denis Hanson's [proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes) that $\prod\limits_{p^a \le n} < 3^n$, I am confused by the final step.

He proceeds to show that:

$$C(n) = \frac{n!}{\lfloor n/a_1\rfloor!\lfloor n/a_2\rfloor!\lfloor n/a_3\rfloor!\dots} < e^{k-3/2}n^{k-3/2}w^n$$

for $k > 2$ and $w < 2.952$

Then, he mentions that:

> A check of tables reveals that $C(n) < 3^n$ for $n > 1300$

What table is he referring to?  And how is this possible given the value of $w$.  How can $(en)^{k-3/2}$ possibly be less than $3^{n - 2.952}$?

Am I misunderstanding the last step?  Did I mistake a mistake in any of my statement above?  If not, could someone send me a reference to the tables and explain how the tables establish the conclusion.

Comment: Use Lemma 5 to bound the growth of $(en)^k$ and then do some estimation to get this number 1300.

Comment: Sorry.  What are the tables that the proof is referring to?  Thanks.

Comment: Presumably log tables,  Remember, scientific pocket calculator wasn't available then.

Comment: Thanks.  I have never used log tables.  I’ll review them.  That helps.  I’ll review Lemma 5.